# JS: output inconsistencies

Tags: javascript, html

This code gets the user input and substitute it to "selected", Example

1st Input
User Input:

```
Apple
```

Process(what happens inside):

```
"img2/" + Apple + ".jpg";
```

Output:

```
Apple.jpg (image)
```

The problem is once the user inputs a query that doesn't have the corresponding image the code, outputs the previous one

2nd Input
User Input:

```
Orange
```

Process(what happens inside):

```
"img2/" + Apple + ".jpg";
```

Output:

```
Apple.jpg (image) //wrong incorrect

 var q = document.getElementById("code");


if (q.selectedIndex > 0) { 

var selected = q.options[q.selectedIndex].value;
var src = "img2/" + selected + ".jpg";
var img = document.getElementById("placeholderImg");
img.src = src;
img.style.display = "inline";

}

<select name="code" id="code" size="" disabled="true" hidden="true">
<option value="Apple">Apple</option>
<option value="Atis">Atis</option>
//so on and so forth
```

how can I fix this? any suggestion opinion is highly appreciated

Comment: where is q.selectedIndex defined?

Comment: @Sam i updated it so you can see were q.selectedIndex is defined

Comment: Is it because `if (q.selectedIndex > 0) {` fails so that block is never executed?

Comment: on the contrary that block always works, so even if the user inputs a query that doesn't have a corresponding image it still output the previous image because "selected" 's value is never changed and that is my problem

Comment: So how could a user input a value that wasn't in the select box?

Comment: there is a textarea where the user can input there query, then that query's value will be pass to the select box, if the query is found it will output an image

Comment: So then what's the point of the select box at all?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your mistake lays within the line

```
if (q.selectedIndex > 0)
```

The `selectedIndex` property is `0` when the first row is selected (in your case "Apple").
Therefor this if statement will only work if something else than "Apple" is selected.
The `selectedIndex` property is `-1` when nothing is selected, not `0`!

You should replace it with the following statement:

```
if (q.selectedIndex > -1)
```

Comment: sorry sir the same problem occurs

Comment: @SOS Can you then setup a fiddle to reproduce your error at http://jsfiddle.net/ ?